# Deserialize datetime with value null with Serializer Component Symfony4.4

Tags: symfony4

I get an error when I try to deserialize an object which contains an attribute of type `datetime` but its value is `null`:

> The data is either an empty string or null, you should pass a string that can be parsed with the passed format or a valid DateTime string.